# How to compare timespan before and after?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, compare, timespan

I wanted to compare a timespan before and after 3 hours. For example, a cinema halls, I wanted to check the hall on the specific date is the hours chosen can fit into it. If that day has movie on that hall, then the hours can only be 3 hours before or 3 hours after the movie.

I know that timespan can add but I can't think of a way to actually do the algorithm.Here's the part of the code I'm trying to figure out `TimeSpan.Parse(cbxTime.Text)` part what should be added

```
  If hall1.Checked = True Then
                For Each g In db.Shows

                    If g.hallId = "H1" Then
                        If g.showDate = CDate(dtpDate.Text) Then
                            If g.showTime > TimeSpan.Parse(cbxTime.Text) 3 hours OR < TimeSpan.Parse(cbxTime.Text)3 hours   Then
                                Can proceed to Adding Show Time
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
                a.hallId = "H1"
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim result As Integer = TimeSpan.Compare(before, after)
```

result will be -`1, 0` or `1`

`1` = the left one is bigger

`0` = equal

`-1` = right one is bigger

[link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.compare(v=vs.110).aspx) to full explanation

Comment: `int result` I would have to say that is not `vb.net` AndAlso this is not `c#` syntax either `int result = TimeSpan.Compare(before, after)` ...

Comment: Actually, i understand this part. Just that the part I don't know is the before part

Comment: are you asking about this line? `g.showTime > TimeSpan.Parse(cbxTime.Text) 3 hours OR < TimeSpan.Parse(cbxTime.Text)3 hours   Then`

Comment: ya how do i get the 3hours before and after

Comment: I did manage to get after by using `.hours(3)` and save inside another value

Comment: `Dim 3hoursDiff As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(3)`

Comment: `g.showTime > (TimeSpan.Parse(cbxTime.Text)+3hoursDiff)`